# How to use the Limit Comparison Test or Comparison Test Instead of Integral Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For the infinite series $$\sum_{n=4}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln(n^2)} $$
  I found a solution with the integral test that proves its divergence. However, I was expected to use either the limit comparison test or comparison test instead of the integral test. I can't quite figure out how to apply either test in this situation.

Comment: Try to apply the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Bertrand series http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html

Comment: This doesn't look like a Bertrand series because it's the ln(n^2) not ln(n)

Comment: $\ln(n^2)=2\ln(n)$ and you pull the $\frac{1}{2}$ out of the sum.

Comment: Oh, I see, so I should then use the comparison test with 1/n?

Comment: @Math123 Comparison test with $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ doesn't work here.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, you need a series that is less then or equal to yours and prove that it diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln(n^2)} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac{1}{k\ln(k^2)} \geq \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^{n+1}-2^n-1}{2^{n+2}\ln(2^{n+1})} \geq \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{n+2}\ln(2^{n+1})} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{8n\ln2}  $$

[See Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) for formalization of a general theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln (n^2) = 2 \ln n$$  Factor out the 1/2.  The integral of $$1/{(n\ln n)}$$ is $$\ln \ln n$$ (u-sub w/ $\ln x$ ).  This clearly does not converge, and therefore the infinite sum does not either by the integral test.

Comment: That's the solution I found with the integral test, but the issue is that I need to prove divergence with either comparison test.

Comment: Perhaps you are overthinking this.  If you are allowed to use the limit comparison test, compare it with 1/ nlnn .  The ratio goes to 1/2